# list of wpa_supplicant error messages

Tags: debugging, wpa-supplicant, testing

I'm trying to write a test to debug a network manager that utilises `wpa_supplicant` but I'm having a hard time finding a list of error messages that I can expect for `CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED` events.

I have currently found only the following two but I am interested to know if there are more:

- `WRONG_KEY`
- `CONN_FAILED`

Does anyone know of the existence of a list of these messages and their causes?

Note: I have tried searching [the source code](http://w1.fi/cgit/hostap-1/commit/?id=f5c21f96d322932aa7ccf1b21956fdda530d161c) but references to these errors do not even seem to exist there. Are these messages caused by the interface card itself then?